# How to add array values to Eloquent ORM ::get() output

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent

## Background

So I run code like this `M_Site::get()` and it produces an output value like this:

```
"MSite": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Sudirman",
                "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Cibinong",
                "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Tanah Merdeka",
                "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
```

### Value to add

I just want to add an extra prefix value in the beginning like this:

```
[
    "id" => 0,
    "name" => "All Branch",
    "created_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
    "updated_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
    "created_by" => 1,
    "updated_by" => null,
    "deleted_at" => null,
]
```

#### Try 1

I've tried the way with adding values like adding values to a regular array like this:

```
$m_site = [
    [
        "id" => 0,
        "name" => "All Branch",
        "created_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
        "created_by" => 1,
        "updated_by" => null,
        "deleted_at" => null,
    ],
    M_Site::get()
];
```

But failed, the result is like this:

```
"MSite": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "All Branch",
                "created_at": "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sudirman",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Cibinong",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Tanah Merdeka",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            ]
        ]
```

#### Try 2

I've also tried using the `push` function from [Laravel's Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-push) like this:

```
$m_site = collect([
    "id" => 0,
    "name" => "All Branch",
    "created_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
    "updated_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
    "created_by" => 1,
    "updated_by" => null,
    "deleted_at" => null,
]);

$m_site->push(M_Site::get());
```

But failed, the result is like this:

```
"MSite": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "All Branch",
            "created_at": "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": null,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "0": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Sudirman",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Cibinong",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Tanah Merdeka",
                    "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                    "created_by": 1,
                    "updated_by": null,
                    "deleted_at": null
                }
            ]
        }
```

#### Expectations

What I want is a result like this:

```
"MSite": 
        {
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "All Branch",
                "created_at": "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null,
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Sudirman",
                "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:47.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Cibinong",
                "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:09:56.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Tanah Merdeka",
                "created_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-09-25T23:10:08.000000Z",
                "created_by": 1,
                "updated_by": null,
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        }
```

How to generate it like that?

Comment: Instead of `push` try with `prepend`.

Comment: Okay, i'll try it

Comment: Whoa it works, thanks! Dont you want to answer it? So i can accept it

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, thank you, but before I could even get to the documentation about the collection, I've been trying to find it everywhere. Until now I only found out after being explained in detail by others. Maybe I wasn't careful before

Comment: no worries at all! You now know where it is. Other stuff is explained similarly so have a good eye on the docs. If you are not able to understand something, try it out, and is not working, post a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`prepend()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-prepend)

> The `prepend` method adds an item to the beginning of the collection:

```php
$m_site = M_Site::get()->prepend((object)[
    "id" => 0,
    "name" => "All Branch",
    "created_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
    "updated_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
    "created_by" => 1,
    "updated_by" => null,
    "deleted_at" => null,
]);
```

[`concat()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-concat)

> The `concat` method appends the given array or collection's values
> onto the end of another collection:

```php
$m_site = collect([
    (object)[
        "id" => 0,
        "name" => "All Branch",
        "created_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at" => "0000-00-25T23:00:00.000000Z",
        "created_by" => 1,
        "updated_by" => null,
        "deleted_at" => null,
    ],
])->concat(M_Site::get());
```